# The order of middleware in Express 4

Tags: node.js, express

Why if I put this

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
});

app.use('/', index);
```

All request are 404?
The order of middleware is important?

Comment: Yes the order is important. What do you expect it to do? You have one middleware, and one error middleware. Error middleware is only called after calling `next(err)`. Where `err` is not **null**.

Comment: @Jordonias I expect that 404 is call when the route dosen't fine any match.

Comment: next(), call the "next" function that it finds ?

Comment: `next()` with no `err` calls the next middleware that doesn't have 4 arguments (`req, res` or `req, res, next`), while `next(err)` calls the next middleware with 4 arguments (`err, req, res, next`)

Comment: I have written an article on importance of middleware order in Express application .Here is the link to the article: https://www.nodexplained.com/blog-detail/2018/01/11/importance-of-middleware-order-in-expressjs-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes order matters.
If you move `app.use('/', index)` before the **404** middleware and the **error** middleware it will work as expected.